# Fastest Way to Parse Large Strings (multi threaded)

Tags: c#, regex, parsing, string, parallel-processing

I am about to start a project which will be taking blocks of text, parsing a lot of data into them into some sort of object which can then be serialized, stored, and statistics / data gleaned from. This needs to be as fast as possible as I have > 10,000,000 blocks of text that I need to start on and will be getting 100,000's of thousands a day.

I am running this on a system with 12 xeon cores + hyper threading. I also have access / know a bit about CUDA programming but for string stuff think that its not appropriate. From each string I need to parse a lot of data and some of it I know the exact positions of, some I don't and need to use regex's / something smart.

So consider something like this:

```
object[] parseAll (string [] stringsToParse)
{
     parallel foreach 
          parse( string[n] )
}

object parse(string s)
{
     try to use exact positions / substring etc here instead of regex's
}
```

So my questions are:

- How much slower is using regex's to substr.
- Is .NET going to be significantly slower than other languages.
- What sort of optimizations (if any) can I do to maximize parallelism.
- Anything else I haven't considered?

Thanks for any help! Sorry if this is long winded.

Comment: My guess is IO will be the limiting factor. Setup some simple test-cases and profile your resource usage, etc.

Comment: On a modern PC, the volume you spoke of is small fry for datawarehousing work.  The method you propose sounds, er, sound.  Consider also using things like IndexOf when you know you can search for a fixed string safely.  Avoid ToUpper/Lower if you can, if the comparison functions support ignoring case.  But first off, write for readability, then optimise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**How much slower is using regex's to substr.**
If you are looking for an exact string, substr will be faster. Regular expressions however are highly optimized. They (or at least parts) are compiled to IL and you can even store these compiled versions in a separate assembly using `Regex.CompileToAssembly`. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ek5zak6.aspx for more information.

What you really need to do is do perform measurements. Using something like `Stopwatch` is by far the easiest way to verify whether one or the other code construct works faster.

**What sort of optimizations (if any) can I do to maximize parallelism.**
With `Task.Factory.StartNew`, you can schedule tasks to run on the thread pool. You may also have a look at the TPL (Task Parallel Library, of which `Task` is a part). This has lots of constructs that help you parallelize work and allows constructs like `Parallel.ForEach()` to execute an iteration on multiple threads. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx for more information.

**Anything else I haven't considered?**
One of the things that will hurt you with this volume of data is memory management. A few things to take into account:

- Limit memory allocation: try to re-use the same buffers for a single document instead of copying them when you only need a part. Say you need to work on a range starting at char 1000 to 2000, don't copy that range into a new buffer, but construct your code to work only in that range. This will make your code complexer, but it saves you memory allocations;
- `StringBuilder` is an important class. If you don't know of it yet, have a look.

Comment: Completely agreed. In particular beware the memory allocation part. With such an high volume it may be possible to suffer from memory fragmentation. I suggest you read and understand this if you haven't already: http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/the-dangers-of-the-large-object-heap/

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what kind of processing you're doing here, but if you're talking hundreds of thousands of strings per day, it seems like a pretty small number.  Let's assume that you get 1 million new strings to process every day, and you can fully task 10 of those 12 Xeon cores.  That's 100,000 strings per core per day.  There are 86,400 seconds in a day, so we're talking 0.864 seconds per string.  That's a *lot* of parsing.

I'll echo the recommendations made by @Pieter, especially where he suggests making measurements to see how long it takes to do your processing.  Your best bet is to get something up and working, *then* figure out how to make it faster if you need to.  I think you'll be surprised at how often you don't need to do any optimization.  (I know that's heresy to the optimization wizards, but processor time is cheap and programmer time is expensive.)

> How much slower is using regex's to substr?

That depends entirely on how complex your regexes are.  As @Pieter said, if you're looking for a single string, `String.Contains` will probably be faster.  You might also consider using `String.IndexOfAny` if you're looking for constant strings.  Regular expressions aren't necessary unless you're looking for patterns that can't be represented as constant strings.

> Is .NET going to be significantly slower than other languages?

In processor-intensive applications, .NET can be slower than native apps.  Sometimes.  If so, it's typically in the range of 5 to 20 percent, and most often between 7 and 12 percent.  That's just the code executing in isolation.  You have to take into account other factors like how long it takes you to build the program in that other language and how difficult it is to share data between the native app and the rest of your system.

Comment: Your calculations assume perfect distribution vs time.  In many scenarios, his load could be double or more during peak times.  (which still might not be a ton of processing time, but no reason to throw math at something when you only have 1/10th the required statistics to actually solve the problem/tell him if he needs to buy more servers :).

Comment: @Merlyn: Yes, I ignored peaks.  I also over-estimated the daily load.  In addition, there was no mention of needing this to be "real time."  I interpreted the question as "how do I keep up with the load?" and my answer reflects that.  Yes, there might be items left in a queue during peak periods.  But that's almost always the case unless you design the system for the peak, meaning that you have idle hardware during off-peak times.

Comment: True. It all depends on what his real requirements are. "Fast as possible" shows that he wants a good response time, or at least good turn-around time, but it also shows he doesn't know what he needs to look at in order to guarantee any specific level of service.  I think giving math vs the data he has now may give him a false sense of security that he has properly examined his requirements, and will be meeting them.  BTW, I'm also thinking in terms of a networked service.  His app may not reflect that, in which case simple perf metrics may be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Google had recently announced it's internal text processing language (which seems like a Python/Perl subset made for heavily parallel processing).

http://code.google.com/p/szl/ - Sawzall.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do fast string parsing in C#, you might want to consider having a look at the new [NLib](http://driftertech.somee.com/) project. It contains string extensions to facilitate searching strings in various ways rapidly. Such as, IndexOfAny(string[]) and IndexOfNotAny. They contain overloads with a StringComparison argument too.